# Is there Encoder/Decoder available for windows phone to convert Wav to Mp3 and Mp3 to Wav?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Even after spending a lot of time in searching an audio encoder/decoder, I can't find a single one which we can use for windows phone application.

I've seen many like lame, naudio, nspeex and so on.

Somebody please tell me; Is there an audio encoder/decoder to be used in windows phone application which is capable of converting Mp3 to Wav or Wav to Mp3?

Comment: there is an ffmmpg libraray,but not sure how to use it

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you need a license to encode MP3 if you are doing it to generate revenue? http://mp3licensing.com/royalty/emd.html

Comment: @DanielHilgarth S Sir I do know that, i'm just learning windows phone application development.

Comment: Alright. I guess what I wanted to say was: You might want to think about using an open format like Ogg Vorbis instead of MP3.

Comment: That won't work on windows phone, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be: no there is no free mp3 encoder/decoder for windows phone.

Comment: That means there is(for cost)! what are they